# How to serialize LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-linearlayout

I have a linearLayout. I add dynamically several TextView with some text in linearLayout. After additions (1 - 1000 TextView) I want to save my linearLayout in file. After that I close and open again my app and I have to restore linearLayout from the file. I thought make it using `ObjectOutputStream` and method `writeObject()`.

```
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
os.writeObject(linearLayout);
```

but linearLayout is not serializable

```
java.io.NotSerializableException
```

How can do this?

Comment: Can you use a ListView for whatever it is you're trying to do? That sounds much more reasonable than a really long dynamic LinearLayout.

Comment: And how save and restore listView, perform operations with its adapter?

Comment: Yes. You can write a method in your adapter somehow to print all items, and then read all items back to rebuild the adapter.

Comment: use a listview & adapter

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try it

Comment: I think your approach to the problem is wrong, you should persist your **data sources** and use `RecyclerView` or `ListView` with vew holder pattern to avoid recreating so much views.

Comment: Can any one resolve this issue? Because I have a model class in which I'm using MarginLayoutParams and I want to serialize this model class. Now MarginLayoutParams is not serializable so that it's throwing NotSerializableException.